# suddenly cannot sftp - Connection reset by peer

Tags: ssh, sftp

From ubuntu client, I suddenly cannot sftp, this is the verbose output:

```
    sftp -vvv user@test.com
    OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
    debug2: resolving "test.com" port 22
    debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to test.com [159.83.131.165] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/deploy/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/deploy/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/deploy/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/deploy/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/deploy/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
    debug1: identity file /home/deploy/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10
    ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
    Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

I've tried updating hosts.allow and changing the timeout as suggested in other posts but can't seem to get anywhere.  This used to work just fine.  Does the output suggest the server stopped accepting the currently available local certs and I need to generate a new one?  If so can someone help with how? If not any other ideas?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: Does scp or rsync work ?

Comment: no, same or similar message

Comment: Try moving aside all your extra ssh keys so there's no multiple key attempts and see if that helps

Comment: Do you have access to the openssh server ? The logs from it could help you identify the problem.